# Python config files that need to be in specific location

Tags: python, linux, config, setup.py, python-packaging

I am working on a python plugin for a program let's call it someapp. When the python package installs, a config file ./configfiles/myplugin.config needs to be copied to /etc/someapp/config.d/myplugin.config

The app is coded so a config file is neccesary for the plugin to be usable. What should I write in setup.py for this behaviour?

Comment: This seems to violate the encapsulation provided by virtual environments. I'd highly recommend seeking a different approach. Definitely not an answer, but certainly something to consider.

Comment: Same. I would not recommend doing this. You can probably do it with _setuptools_ `data_files`. But that is not what _setuptools_ is good at. For these kinds of things you should package your code in the format of the Linux distribution (_apt/`.deb`, _yum_/`.rpm`, _pacman_, etc.).

Comment: I have preinstalled plugin and when I do dpkg -L otherplugin it shows the path /etc/someapp/config.d/otherplugin.config so I think that plugin included the config at install